# How to disable scrollTop() effect after click on onClick() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using `scrollTop()` event to show/hide div in certain position also I am using `onClick()` event to permanently hide div, the event is working good but the problem is that when i scrolling page then the div showing again.
My code is as under.

**Javascript code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        if (screen.width > 768) {
            var y = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (y < 500) {
                $('.benchdiv').fadeOut();
            }
            else {
                $('.benchdiv').fadeIn();
            }
        }
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".removebg").click(function(){
            $(".benchdiv").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="benchdiv">
    <a href="http://www.benchmarkemail.com?p=636276" target=_blank><img src="//www.benchmarkemail.com/images/partner/banners/125x125.gif" width="125" height="125" border="0" /></a>
    <div class="benchremove"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="removebg glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></a></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Try using a bool that indicates if you have enter on ".removebg" function and check it before fadeIn the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$(".benchdiv").remove();
```

instead of

```
$(".benchdiv").hide();
```

to permanently remove the div.

Works?

Answer (score 0):

You can either Remove the element:

```
$(".benchdiv").remove();
```

or if you will use it later you  can do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clicked = false;
    $(document).scroll(function() {
  if(!clicked){
        if (screen.width > 768) {
            var y = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (y < 500) {
                $('.benchdiv').fadeOut();
            }
            else {
                $('.benchdiv').fadeIn();
            }
        }
      }
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".removebg").click(function(){
            $(".benchdiv").hide();
            clicked = true;
        });
    });
</script>
```